# Why is my variable NULL? Trying to put result from mysql query into variable

Tags: php, mysql

Ok so Im trying to select a link from my db, get the text from the page, parse it and put that in a different column on the same row and repeat. I keep getting an error saying "file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty" So I figured its the variable that represents the link must be empty. Did a `mysql_fetch_row($result);` and sure enough, my `$link_result` is NULL. I dont understand why though. Help? Heres the code so far:

```
$x = 1;

    for ($y=1;$y=1201;$y++)
    {
    $query1 = "SELECT adlink, key  FROM usedcars WHERE key = $x";

    mysqli_query($conn, $query1);

    $link_result = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);

    file_get_contents($link_result);
    $text_holder = file_get_contents($link_result);

    return_between($text_holder, "postingBody", "<!-- .posting -->", EXCL);
    $final_text = return_between($text_holder, "postingBody", "<!-- .posting -->", EXCL);

    $query2 = "INSERT INTO usedcars (adtext) VALUES ($final_text) WHERE key = $x";

    mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
    echo "<font size='18' color='#FFFF00'>Placing text from $link_result into database</font><br>"; 

    $x++;
    }
```

Im obviously very new so any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: I will definitely add the quotes thank you. Any idea why the $link_result is NULL? @Arif_suhail_123

Comment: You cannot get the result using mysql_query directly, you have to do mysqli_fetch_row or mysqli_fetch_assoc or mysqli_fetch_object to get the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use `file_get_contents` to fetch those values

Use `mysqli_fetch_*`

```
$link_result = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);

$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($link_result);
```

If you're expecting multiple rows then use a `while()`:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($link_result)) {
    $link = $row['adlink'];
}
```

Comment: The query returns a link, the file_get_contents was supposed to download the html for that link. Does this still apply? @Ghost

Comment: @tommyg `mysqli_query` returns a resource object, from that resource object, you need to fetch results, and by that use the fetch functions, once you have fetched the rows, then get those links

Comment: @tommyg and mind those other answers, also, arif's and rahul's. compile our answers and it should make up a working one,

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 yeah, our answers should pretty much sum up all the basic things needed to get these codes going.

Comment: Thanks @Ghost I'll take a minute and try to put it together.

Comment: Got it working! Idk how you are always on here, but you're my savior, man...my own personal jesus christ! Thanks again! @Ghost

Answer (score 2):

`key` is mysql reserve words. use bacticks around it

```
 $query1 = "SELECT adlink, `key`  FROM usedcars WHERE `key` = $x";
```

and to fetch the value use `mysqli_fetch_array` or `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

This line is wrong

```
$query2 = "INSERT INTO usedcars (adtext) VALUES ($final_text) WHERE key = $x";
```

and you can not use `where clause` in insert statement. But you can do some thing like this, i think you need `update` `query` instead of insert.

Like this

```
$query2 =UPDATE usedcars SET adtext ='$final_text' WHERE `key` = $x;
```

Comment: you can't even follow your own advice.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about PHP but in your `SELECT` statement you are using a reserve word `key` which must be escaped using backtique like

```
SELECT adlink, `key`  FROM usedcars WHERE `key` = $x
```

Again, your `INSERT` statement format is wrong as pointed below. You don't use `WHERE` clause in `INSERT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO usedcars (adtext) VALUES ($final_text) WHERE key = $x
                                                    <-- Here
```

I think you meant to do an `UPDATE` rather like

```
UPDATE usedcars SET adtext = $final_text WHERE `key` = $x
```